# Assign additional field when unmarshalling JSON object to struct

Tags: json, go, struct

What is the best way to assign additional field to struct and all it references sub-structure when encoding it from []byte and this field is not a part of unmarshalling []byte?

Let me clarify by example...

1. We have a few struct:

```
    type Update struct {
        UpdateID int32 `json:"update_id"`
        Message *Message `json:"message,omitempty"`
        ...
    }

    type Message struct {
        MessageID int32 `json:"message_id"`
        From *User `json:"from,omitempty"`
        Date int32 `json:"date"`
        Chat Chat `json:"chat"`
        ...
    }
```

2. Our core struct is APIClient and it has many methods for send something or get something (API wrapper)

```
    type API struct {
        Token string
        PollInt int32
        URL string

        client *http.Client
    }

    func(a *API) ... () {

    }

    func(a *API) ... () {

    }

    ...
```

3. Main loop poller make http request and return json response as "res" – []byte, so we can use json.Unmarshal to map it to special Update struct

```
    func (a *API) GetUpdates(ctx context.Context, gu *GetUpdates) ([]Update, error) {
        buf := bytes.Buffer{}
        err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(gu)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("getupdates: %s", err)
        }

        res, err := a.DoRequest(&ctx, "getUpdates", &buf)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("getupdates: %s", err)
        }

        var result []Update
        err = json.Unmarshal(res.Result, &result)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("getupdates: %s", err)
        }

        return result, nil
    }
```

4. Is it any way to extend ALL structs in unmarhsaling chain for a additional field when use json.Unmarshal

```
    type Update struct {
        UpdateID int32 `json:"update_id"`
        Message *Message `json:"message,omitempty"`
        ...

        API `json:"-"`
    }

    type Message struct {
        MessageID int32 `json:"message_id"`
        From *User `json:"from,omitempty"`
        Date int32 `json:"date"`
        Chat Chat `json:"chat"`
        ...

        API `json:"-"`
    }
```

So we can do something like:

```
    var result []Update
    err = json.Unmarshal(res.Result, &result, api)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("getupdates: %s", err)
    }
```

And then use it:

```
    result[0].RejectUpdate()
    result[0].Message.SendReply()
    ...
    func (u *Update) RejectUpdate(cause string) {
      m.API.SendMessage(u.Chat.ID, text)
      m.API.Reject(u.ID, cause)
    }
    func (m *Message) SendReply(text string) {
      m.API.SendMessage(m.Chat.ID, text)
    }
```

All struct will be extended by api (embedded struct) on unmarshaling...

My thoughts about solution:

1. Patch standard encoding/json library – not a good choice
2. Get custom encoding library and rewrite a little bit – questionable choice
3. Manually unmarshal all object – awful code

```
   type Bot struct {
        superCLient string
    }

    type Image struct {
        Name string
        Path string

        *Bot `json:"-"`
    }

    type FormFile struct {
        Img  *Image
        Name string

        *Bot `json:"-"`
    }

    func main() {
        data := []byte(`{"Img": {"Name": "Vi", "Path": "/etc/log"}, "Name": "Josh"}`)
        bot := &Bot{
            superCLient: "ClientExample",
        }
        var omg FormFile
        omg.CustomUnmarshal(data, bot)
        fmt.Println(omg)
    }

    func (ff *FormFile) CustomUnmarshal(data []byte, bot *Bot) error {
        var f map[string]*json.RawMessage
        json.Unmarshal(data, &f)

        var i Image
        i.CustomUnmarshal(*f["Img"], bot)
        ff.Img = &i

        json.Unmarshal(*f["Name"], ff.Name)

        ff.Bot = bot

        return nil
    }

    func (img *Image) CustomUnmarshal(data []byte, bot *Bot) error {
        err := json.Unmarshal(data, img)
        img.Bot = bot
        return err
    }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you define interfaces for all possible structures the response can have and add pointers to those in your master interface?

Comment: Didn't understand your idea, can your explain it with a code sketch?

Comment: Closely {... *MessageIntreface *ChatInterface } then you can write custom Unmarshallers for those types just by defining UnmarshalJSON method

Comment: Most probably you should not do any of that, the idea of your types (Update, Message, etc.) having a reference to a copy of the API type seems like an awful design decision. But if you decide to go ahead with the idea then options 1. 2. and 3. are, in my opinion, all wrong with number 1 being the worst offender. The least awkward approach I can think of is to write a function that uses the reflect package to set every field of type API, and you would call this function after you've obtained your result and not during unmarshaling. e.g. `res := unmarshal(data); populate(res, api)`.